# browser.runtime.sendMessage API send large data slowly on Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I use browser.runtime.sendMessage API of firefox extension (firefox 54- 64 bit) send message has large binary data from contentscript to background.

**Send message very slowly and make firefox is not responding in 3-5s depending on the data size that contentscript send**. Then it works normally and background receive message.

**On chrome sendMessage API work quickly and very very smooth.**

How can I fix it in firefox?

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage(tab.id, { name: "sendScreen", data: { screen: screen} })
```

**screen value in object is binary data (array with length ~ 1135609)**.

In background.js I add listener message:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener (message, sender, sendResponse);
```

Manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "abc",

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon_19.png",
    "default_popup": "login.html",
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "web_accessible_resources": [


        "js/contentscripts/Browser.js",

      ],
      "js": [
        "js/contentscripts/ContentScript.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "file://*/*",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    },
    {
      "js": [

        "js/contentscripts/Browser.js",
      ],
      "matches": [
        "file://*/*",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon_16.png",
    "19": "icons/icon_19.png"
  },
  "incognito": "spanning",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: A pretty significant bug was recently fixed in this area:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1356546

The fix is only in Firefox 55 though, can you try a Beta or Dev Edition or Nightly build and see if there's a noticeable difference?

Comment: Break the data into multiple pieces and send the pieces separately, with a `setTimeout()` delay between sending. Even if the delay in your `setTimeout()` is 0ms, it will still allow FF to do other things in between the different messages. While this won't, necessarily, speed up the overall process, it should prevent FF from freezing.

Comment: Are you running in multiprocess mode, or single process? Please provide a complete [mcve] which can be used to duplicate the problem. Having the MCVE just send dummy data may be easier than including everything needed to construct your actual data. If the problem is not resolved in FF55, we are going to need enough to [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi).

Comment: You could try using the Broadcast Channel api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API

Comment: It work well on firefox 55 beta :), How can I temporary fix in FF54? while wating FF55 is released?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the [bug 1356546](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1356546) mentioned didn't resolve the issue then [file a new firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Toolkit&component=WebExtensions:%20General).

Otherwise you can try to split your data up as was mentioned in comments, that wouldn't reduce the overall time, but it might reduce the affect on UX, or just don't support Firefox until they fix their webextensions bugs.